# Using Quick Add Next to add to a selection using find, I want to SKIP some matches

Tags: sublimetext2

This [documentation for sublime2](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html) describes nicely how to use (on OS X) command-D to add the next match to a selection started with find, and if you "go too far" use command-U to back up without starting all over.

I would like to use command-D to add the next match, but then when I come across a match that I want to EXCLUDE from the selection, skip over it and continue adding the later matches.

Is that possible?

Is it added to sublime3 maybe?

TIA,
Marla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd+k` followed by `cmd+d` will do what you want.

Comment: Yes!  but it is a little weird.  There is no visual feedback that it worked until you do the subsequent cmd+d.  Then you can see that the skipped item is, indeed, omitted from the selection, and typing affects the others, not it.  Perfect!  Thanks!